# how to store string in isolated storage setting?

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have there are so many city name. And i wants to store this city into my device data base. And i use isolated storage setting but isolatad storage allow me to add only one city.And how to display this city ?

my C# code is for storing city is:

```
if (!setting.Contains("CityDetail"))
            {

                setting.Add("CityDetail", cityname);

                //MessageBox.Show(cityname + "  is successfully added in the favorites");
            }
            else
            {
                cityname = (string)setting["CityDetail"];


                //MessageBox.Show(cityname + "  is allready added in the favorites");
            }
            //setting.Save();
```

Comment: can you explain what you want to do? what is the problem with the code (except for the error where you sometimes write CityDeltai and sometimes CityDetail)

Comment: @igrali:sry now see my edited code and give me answer and i want to add city name in my data base and city name is came from dynemically and its more than two.and now i want to display this city name in to another page list view

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to save a list of cities in Phone, if that is the case then it is advised that you should prefer either **Local SQL Database** or **XML**. This way you can have any type of **Persistent Data** in your app. It might be a list of cities or some complex object.

To learn more see:
[**Local SQL Database**](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.1-Local-SQL-Database.aspx) and [**Read and Save XML Files**](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files).

If you need **to save** it in Isolated Storage Settings (due to some unavoidable reason), Then you need to change `key` part of `key-value` pair to some **dynamic value** (say city1, city2, city3....)

```
setting.Add("city1", city1);
```

And Later  **to retrieve** all cities you can use loop such as

```
for(int i=0; i<totalCities ; i++)
{
 //prepare key value
String cityNumber = "city" + i;

String cityName = settings[cityNumber].ToString();
//here you get your city name Add it to a list or Array

}
```

Note that you need to store Number of Cities in Application Settings and Update them and Assign them to `totalCities`.

**Edit:**

Save the number of cities to a app setting (say "totalCities"):
every time you add a city, update the number of cities like this

```
    void Update()
{    
int presentCities;

//Retrieve present number of cities
presentCities = (string)setting["totalCities"];

//Save updated valu to application setting
Add.Settings("totalCities", presentCities + 1); 

 }
```

To retrieve just use `(int)setting["totalCities"]`

Comment: :here you describe String cityNumber = "city" + i; so what is the value of "city"?

Comment: "city" is just a String, because we saved cities with key name 'city1, city2,...... , so we need to retrieve it using same names.

Answer (score 1):

The Isolated Storage Settings is effectively an implementation of a generic Dictionary.  It contains key-value pairs and all of the keys in the collection must be unique (just like a Dictionary).  I *think* that you're wanting to store more than one city name.  You will either have to use multiple keys,

```
 setting.Add("City1", city1);
 setting.Add("City2", city2);
 setting.Add("City3", city3);
```

or you could store an array under a single key:

```
 setting.Add("Cities", new string[] { city1, city2, city3 });
```

Not sure which is more appropriate, as it's not entirely clear in your question.

Comment: :thanks but actully number of city is not fix this code is good for three citys but when fourth one is came at that time what?

Comment: and how to retrive this cities bcos i m using  retrivecity = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Cities"] as string; so null value are caming

Comment: It's an array.  It can hold any number of items, not just 3.

Comment: @hello ctacke i got a solution and thanks for giving me support